# Switch between Equations in a Function

Tags: matlab, function

I'm trying to write at MATLAB function file containing two equations which will switch between the two based of an equality with an input of time.

i.e.

```
  if vc(t) <= |vt*cos(2*pi*f*t)|

      Execute Equation 1

  if vc(t) > |vt*cos(2*pi*f*t)|

      Execute Equation 2
```

I want the function to be able to start with the 1st equation (time = 0) and once time reaches a certain value switch to the 2nd equation. Is this possible?

Comment: what is `vc`,`vt`, `f`, etc.? please post the code you already have (i.e. the function, its parameters etc.); also add some demo input and output data (do you want to input vectors, matrices, or just scalars?)

Comment: Have you had an opportunity to look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If the difference between the two equations is basically calling two different functions, you can do this elegantly with the use of function handles.

If in your first case you need

```
some_output=some_function1(var1,var2,var3)
```

and in the second case you need

```
some_output=some_function2(var1,var2,var3)
```

then you can do

```
if vc(t) <= |vt*cos(2*pi*f*t)|
  right_hand_side=@(var1,var2,var3) some_function1(var1,var2,var3);
else
  right_hand_side=@(var1,var2,var3) some_function2(var1,var2,var3);
end

some_output=right_hand_side(var1,var2,var3); %right_hand_side is a function handle to an anonymous function
```

This will also work if you have a simple expression instead of a function, just say something along the lines of `@(var1,var2,var3) 2*var1.*var2./var3;`